# Using JSP tags in another tags

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In my JSP template I have

```
Here is the title: ${title}
```

I want to pass following string (which is served from database) as the title to the view:

```
${appname} - Is the best....
```

Where appname is model attribute. What is the best way to resolve ${appname} in ${title} ?
I am using Spring Webmvc.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this :

```
<c:set var="dynamicAttribute" value="${title}"/>

<c:set var="dynamicAttribute2" value="${fn:substringBefore(dynamicAttribute, '- Is')}" />

${requestScope[dynamicAttribute2]}
```